# Updating Multiple Values with Dict in SQLite (Using Python)

Tags: python, sql, twitter, sqlite

I'm trying to create a SQLite database that stores tweets. Every day I call the API and get 100k or so tweets for a query.

Given that the Twitter API goes back 7 days and some of the values for some of the tweets are bound to change (amount of retweets, favorites, etc), I need a way to update each tweet which is already in the database.

This is how I'm adding the new tweets to the db (where 'parsed' is a list of dicts):

```
# query to add each tweet to the database
for tweet in parsed:
    c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tweets VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
              [tweet['id'],
               tweet['url'],
               tweet['created_at'],
               tweet['hashtags'],
               tweet['favorite_count'],
               tweet['user_mentions'],
               tweet['text'],
               tweet['user_verified'],
               tweet['user_following_count'],
               tweet['retweet_count'],
               tweet['user_name'],
               tweet['user_id'],
               tweet['user_screen_name'],
               tweet['geo'],
               tweet['lang'],
               tweet['user_followers_count']]
             )
```

And this is the query I have so far to update the tweets:

```
update_tweet_query = '''UPDATE tweets
    SET url = ? ,
    created_at = ? ,
    hashtags = ? ,
    favorite_count = ? ,
    user_mentions = ? ,
    text = ? ,
    user_verified = ? ,
    user_following_count = ? ,
    retweet_count = ? ,
    user_name = ? ,
    user_id = ? ,
    user_screen_name = ? ,
    geo = ? ,
    lang = ? ,
    user_followers_count = ?
    WHERE id = ?'''
```

But I'm not sure how to go from here... Am I on the right track? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question... Since there are only two values that change (favorite count and retweet count), there's no use in updating each value. So, while parsing the data, I created another dict which has fluid / dynamic values and updated the db using the following:

```
update_query = 'UPDATE tweets SET favorite_count = ?, retweet_count = ? WHERE id = ?'

for item in parsed[1]:

    # parsed[1][0] = {'favorite_count': 0, 'id': 838564895905964033, 'retweet_count': 229}

    curr_fav_count = item['favorite_count']
    curr_rt_count = item['retweet_count']
    curr_id = item['id']

    c.execute(update_query, (curr_fav_count, curr_rt_count, curr_id))
```